# Add row number as a new column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I need row number 1,2,3,4,5 as new column in below screen shot..

[image]

Query:

```
Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vgid) AS RowNumber, 
    * 
from 
    T_EMS_VGDM_RULEMST 
where 
    VGID in (156, 157, 158, 159, 165) 
order by
    CASE 
       WHEN VGID = 165 then 1    
       WHEN VGID = 158 then 2 
       WHEN VGID = 159 then 3 
       WHEN VGID = 157 then 4 
       WHEN VGID = 156 then 5 
    END
```

Please suggest

Comment: I have modify question with adding ROW_Number but result is not correct

Comment: aah. yes it's working with desc...thanks

Comment: `(ORDER BY vgid DESC)` tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it simply:

```
Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
                                   WHEN VGID = 165 then 1    
                                   WHEN VGID = 158 then 2 
                                   WHEN VGID = 159 then 3 
                                   WHEN VGID = 157 then 4 
                                   WHEN VGID = 156 then 5 
                                END) AS RowNumber
    , * 
    from T_EMS_VGDM_RULEMST 
    where VGID in (156,157,158,159,165) 
    ORDER BY CASE 
     WHEN VGID = 165 then 1    
     WHEN VGID = 158 then 2 
     WHEN VGID = 159 then 3 
     WHEN VGID = 157 then 4 
     WHEN VGID = 156 then 5 
    END
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. also we can avoid order by from where condition.

Comment: The order by is not a where condition. In my experience, when you generate a row number the output follows the ordering, but without an order by there is no guarantee

Answer (score 1):

```
    Select 

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vgid desc) AS RowNumber, 
 * from T_EMS_VGDM_RULEMST where VGID in (156,157,158,159,165) 
ORDER BY CASE 
 WHEN VGID = 165 then 1    
 WHEN VGID = 158 then 2 
 WHEN VGID = 159 then 3 
 WHEN VGID = 157 then 4 
 WHEN VGID = 156 then 5 
END
```